# {{ asset()}}: No route found for "GET /my.htm" (from "http://localhost/Symfony/web/data/live/form/new")

Tags: symfony

I would like to make a link in a form.html.twig
I try like this:

This is a linkt to an htm page

my.htm is saved in the folder web, where the asset() function should look for it.

But I get an error message like this:
No route found for "GET /my.htm" (from "http://localhost/Symfony/web/data/live/form/new")

I tried with ../ but it does not seem to work. 
How should my url look like?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use {{ path() }} for html files.